# No value for argument 'Change' in unbound method call

Tags: python

Currently working through some school assignments and I'm currently stuck on a task that requires call to be made to "IncrementVists" and checks whether it is higher then the capacity, if so then the Outlet related to the Company has their reputation lowered. I've tried using previous questions and I don't seem to be able to find a fix. Any help?

```
  def IncrementVisits(self):
    self._VisitsToday += 1
    if self._Capacity > self._VisitsToday:
      Change = -0.05
      changeRep = Company.AlterReputation()
      changeRep(Change)
      print("More people have attempted to visit your outlet, then your capacity could handle. You reputation has been striked by 0.05")
```

```
class Company:
  def __init__(self, Name, Category, Balance, X, Y, FuelCostPerUnit, BaseCostOfDelivery):
    self._Outlets = []
    self._FamilyOutletCost = 1000
    self._FastFoodOutletCost = 2000
    self._NamedChefOutletCost = 15000
    self._FamilyFoodOutletCapacity = 150
    self._FastFoodOutletCapacity = 200        
    self._NamedChefOutletCapacity = 50
    self._Name = Name
    self._Category = Category
    self._Balance = Balance
    self._FuelCostPerUnit = FuelCostPerUnit
    self._BaseCostOfDelivery = BaseCostOfDelivery
    self._ReputationScore = 100
    self._DailyCosts = 100
    if self._Category == "fast food":
      self._AvgCostPerMeal = 5
      self._AvgPricePerMeal = 10
      self._ReputationScore += random.random() * 10 - 8
    elif self._Category == "family":
      self._AvgCostPerMeal = 12
      self._AvgPricePerMeal = 14
      self._ReputationScore += random.random() * 30 - 5
    else:
      self._AvgCostPerMeal = 20
      self._AvgPricePerMeal = 40
      self._ReputationScore += random.random() * 50
    self.OpenOutlet(X, Y)
```

```
  def AlterReputation(self, Change):
    self._ReputationScore += Change
    return self._ReputationScore
```

Comment: `if self._Capacity > self._VisitsToday:`  => is your sign correct?

Comment: `Company.AlterReputation()`: or do you mean `self.AlterReputation(Change)`?

Comment: More generally, you will have better answer if you provide excepted output of your code vs what it actually does